# getExternalStorageDirectory() on a Chromebook

Tags: android, chromebook

I have an android app that exports files into a sub-directory of [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()). Where will that be on a Chromebook, and what is a standard way for a user to access such files?

A user recently asked where to find the exported files, and I don't have access to a Chromebook to find the answer for myself. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> Where will that be on a Chromebook

Somewhere that the user cannot access, except via Android apps.

Very little is shared, in terms of storage, between the Android realm and the Chrome OS realm, at least at the present time. One thing that *is* shared is the `Downloads` directory, what in Android you would get from `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`. Another is `DIRECTORY_DCIM`, which maps to the "Images" area in Chrome OS.

> I have an android app that exports files into a sub-directory of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

If you are going to ship to Chrome OS devices, the better solution by far is to use the Storage Access Framework. In your case, that would be `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, so you get a `Uri` representing a document tree into which you can export your content. This is different than working with local files, though `DocumentFile` helps mask some of those differences. But, in the end, you are still working with streams to read and write — you just get those streams from a `ContentResolver` instead of from something like `FileOutputStream`.